# How to properly setup Scintilla keyword highlighting?

Tags: delphi, scintilla

I use [`Scintilla`](http://www.scintilla.org/) component with [`DScintilla`](http://code.google.com/p/dscintilla/) wrapper and get error with keyword highlighting in any lexer. Pascal, for example:

```
with DScintilla do 
begin
  SetLexer(SCLEX_PASCAL);
  StyleSetFore(SCE_PAS_WORD, clGreen);
  StyleSetFore(SCE_PAS_OPERATOR, clRed);;
  StyleSetFore(SCE_PAS_IDENTIFIER, clBlue);
  SetText('begin a+b; end');
end
```

This code correctly highlights identifiers and operators, but keywords have the same color as identifiers. It seems that SciLexer can't compare strings inside this library.

How to properly setup Scintilla keyword highlighting ?

Comment: No, SCE_PAS_WORD means keyword. For haskell a constant SCE_HA_KEYWORD is defined, but also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords must be added manually.

```
SetKeyWords(0,'begin end');
```

Comment: This helps though, but it would lose the meaning of the lexer itself, see e.g. into the [`pascal.properties`](http://scintilla.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/scintilla/scite/src/pascal.properties?view=markup), the keywords are already specified there (but don't know if included in the lexer binary).